# Async&Await IL Code

Tags: c#, async-await

If i implement a default async/await method like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().TestMethod();
    }

    private async void TestMethod()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);
    }
}
```

The generated IL-Code and the async state machine contains a field "this" with a reference to the instance which invoked the method. If the code is adjusted to a static one, there is of course no "this" value.

Not to do this via reflection, more from perspective of the CLR or the debugger.
Does anyone know how i can determine within the "static TestMethod" from which method i was called - on the IL level!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestMethod();
    }

    private static async void TestMethod()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't waiting on your awaiter.

Comment: You should not be relying on private implementation details of a feature.  If a given method needs access to a particular instance, you should be explicitly exposing that instance so that you can reliably access it, rather than trying to find private implementation details that may or may not have the information you want.

Comment: I am not relying on that, just wanted to know how the CLR tracks it down to the root of an await...

Comment: The CLR doesn't.  The compiler writes a state machine to convert the code back to the calback pattern.

Comment: how? Any documentation about the generated IL state machine?

Answer (score 4):

> how i can determine within the "static TestMethod" from which method i was called

You can use [`CallerMemberName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)  attribute

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Program().TestMethod();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private async void TestMethod([CallerMemberName]string caller = "")
{
    Console.WriteLine(caller);
}
```

PS: You can also use `CallerFilePath` or `CallerLineNumber`

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Cli
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().TestMethod();
        }

        private void TestMethod()
        {
            var sf = new StackFrame(1); //get caller stackframe
            var mi = sf.GetMethod(); //get method info of caller
            Console.WriteLine("{0}::{1}", mi.DeclaringType, mi.Name);
            // Cli.Program::Main
        }
    }
}
```